# How to read outlook message subject and body from the bytearray of .msg file in python?(without creating .msg file on disk)

Tags: python

I have all the .msg files stored in DB as a binary string. Each row has a binary of .msg file. Now I want to extract message body and subject from that binary. How can I do it?

Option 1:

I am converting this to bytearray, saving it to disk and then create a outlook message object using below code

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")

print msg.SenderName
print msg.SenderEmailAddress
print msg.SentOn
print msg.To
print msg.CC
print msg.BCC
print msg.Subject
print msg.Body

count_attachments = msg.Attachments.Count
if count_attachments > 0:
    for item in range(count_attachments):
        print msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1).Filename

del outlook, msg
```

Doing as above, for every row I am creating a temp file in disk and later deleting it. Is it possible to read the message body and subject without creating the temp file on the disk?

Comment: StringIO is what you're looking for - it acts like a filelike object and can be passed to functions that expect files, check out the docs, it's very handy!

Comment: Thank you,As you suggested I created a ByteIO stream file and wrote the byteAray I have and closed it. But code line msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"myfile.msg") throws error stating msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"myfile.msg")
  File "<COMObject GetNamespace>", line 2, in OpenSharedItem
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "We can't open 'myfile.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)